# Android: auto start an app and exit when finish in onCreate()

Tags: android, oncreate

I want to make a test app, that when called, execute a few lines of code, and then exit automatically.  I want all these done within onCreate().

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate()");
    try {
        initSocket();        //connect to server
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(new AudioRecordThread()).start();
}
```

The problem is, how can I exit the app in onCreate()?  I tried "this.finish()" but didn't work.

## Any one can help?

**EDIT**
I agree that the problem may be caused by thread.  Will post my answer when solved.

Comment: try this YourActivity.this.finish()

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is your `AudioRecordThread` which shares the same Process with your App. You could definetly call this.finish() inside onCreate (done this often, never had problems), but that doesn't mean neccesarily that your `AudioRecordThread` gets killed the same time as your Activity. So without further Information about your Thread, and if it should stay alive on finish of your Activity I cannot give you any advise. If You want that Thread to be alive, after your Activity finishes, a Service is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

finish is working in onCreate() & onResume().. there is another problem in your code

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
     super.onResume();
     finish();
    }
```

Comment: finish is working in onCreate() & onResume().. there is another problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate()");
    try {
        initSocket();        //connect to server
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(new AudioRecordThread()).start();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are trying to do is a service?
Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsynTask in your activity, juste put this class in the Same file of your activity

=> In onPostExecute() methode you will test if your handling is finished to close your activity.

```
class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Init your variables, in my case it's my Progress Bar
        myprogress = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
        myprogress.setTitle("Update");
        myprogress.setMessage("Update running ....");

        myprogress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean test = false;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            j = i + 10;
            publishProgress(i);
            // Your implemention code to connect to the server
            if (i == 49)
                test = true;
        }

        return test;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        myprogress.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (myprogress.isShowing())
            myprogress.dismiss();
        if (result){
            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "I Finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            yourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```